# C# ideal data structure to store 1 float and 3 string fields

Tags: c#, data-structures

What is the ideal data structure I can use in C# to store data consisting of 1 float and 3 string fields (1000+ rows)? I want it such that the structure is easily serializable to a file and can be easily accessed for updating.

Comment: Do you mean "should I use a class or a struct" or something more subtle?

Comment: Are the values fixed upon construction?

Comment: Struct or class... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post an answer that assumes you already considered and dismissed using a class or a struct for some reason.

As a throwback to my graduate school database courses, I kind of like .NET 4.0's introduction of the Tuple class.  If you were so inclined, you could use

```
var myEntry = Tuple<float, string, string, string>(floatVal, string1Val, string2Val, string3Val);
```

and reference the items with

```
float myFloat = myEntry.Item1;
string myString = myEntry.Item2;
```

Tuple is also decorated with the Serializable attribute, so you can serialize them.

Answer (score 8):

A class?!

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public float MyFloat{ get; set; }
   public String StringOne{ get; set; }
   public String StringTwo{ get; set; }
   public String StringThree{ get; set; }
}
```

or possibly a struct!

```
public struct SomeStruct
{
   public float MyFloat{ get; set; }
   public String StringOne{ get; set; }
   public String StringTwo{ get; set; }
   public String StringThree{ get; set; }
}
```

Make sure you understand the difference before choosing one or t'other.